# Reconciling statements about accessible categories

Tags: category-theory, model-theory, accessible-categories

I have a problem reconciling the following assertions regularly made online about accesssible categories:

1. The category $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ of models of some first-order theory $T$ with countable signature is $\aleph _{1}$-accessible. (e.g. stated in the Wikipedia article on accessible categories)
2. A small category is accessible precisely when all idempotents split. (e.g. stated in the nLab article on accessible categories)

From the second assertion it follows that the category $\mathcal{C}$ with one object and one non-trivial idempotent endomorphism, is not acccessible.

Now, take the first-order theory $T$ with one constant symbol $c$, and two axioms:

- $\forall x. \forall y. \forall z. x = y \vee x = z \vee y = z$,
- $\exists x. \exists y. x \neq y$.

The signature of $T$ is countable, so by the first asssertion, it follows that $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ is accessible. But what I'd normally call the category $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ (objects: models of $T$ and morphisms: $c$-homomorphisms) is not accessible: the theory is categorical and the only model has one non-trivial endomorphism (sending everything to $c$), so the skeleton of $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ is in fact isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$ defined above.

**Question: What am I missing?**

I know how to prove Assertion 2 from the definition of acccessible categories, so my guess is that something's wrong with (my interpretation of) Assertion 1. Maybe $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ is intended to refer to a different category (One with different morphisms? Elementary embeddings?), or to a restricted notion of theory $T$.

Comment: The category of models of a general first order theory usually has elementary embeddings as its morphisms.

Comment: @ZhenLin As I wrote, I suspected this was the case (and as a non-category-theorist model-theorist, I am pleasantly surprised ;) ). Can you confirm that there are no further gotchas, and Assertion 1 is correct as stated when $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ has elementary embedding as maps? If so, that's an accepted answer right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chapter 5 of *Locally presentable and accessible categories* it is shown that the category of models of a first order theory *and elementary embeddings* is accessible.
The proof uses the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem.
It is not explicitly calculated, but it should be the case that the category is $\aleph_1$-accessible if the signature is finitary and the language is countable.

I am not sure why the focus is on elementary embeddings.
Perhaps it has to do with the practice of model theory.
However, when working with models of a theory in a more restricted fragment of logic, say geometric logic, category theorists do in fact usually consider the category of models and homomorphisms.

Comment: One justification for focusing on elementary embeddings here: When defining the category Mod(T) of models of a theory T in a logic L, it's natural to take as arrows those maps which preserve all the formulas in L. (E.g. this allows us to view a formula as a functor from Mod(T) to Set.) Elementary embeddings are those maps which preserve all first-order formulas. On the other hand, homomorphisms already preserve all geometric formulas, and many of the other common fragments of first-order logic are contained in geometric logic, so homomorphisms are the natural maps for all these logics.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I think I knew this once upon a time...